# Persist data for 10 entities takes 12 sec

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa, eclipselink

Im using eclipse link with derby DB or MaxDB,when I did performace testing to persist data for 10 entities with 1000 record each this take 12.9 sec ,my code take 0.9 and the **commit** of the entity manager using JPA takes about 12 sec .

1.is it OK that for 10,000 records the time will be 12 secondes?

2.I read that there is option use

```
<property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC" />
```

what is the drawback of using it?how the logging is work?

3.what about using Thread for the commit is it OK?

Comment: how could anyone say if 10000 objects in 12s is fast or not ... it depends on processor, memory, JVM, and other factors. Would be considered incredibly fast on an i386 :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's OK if it's sufficiently fast for you. Only you knows that. You could compare it with code written by hand using JDBC. But don't forget to also take into account the maintainability and the correctness of the code and the time it takes to write and test it. Hardware is cheap. Developers are not. Note that the use-case you tested (inserting lots of rows in lots of tables) is not a very frequent use-case in most typical applications, and not well-suited for JPA, which is typically used to implement short transactions (like buying a book on Amazon, or adding a message in a blog, things like that).
2. No idea.
3. JPA entitymanagers are not thread-safe, and the current transaction is typically associated to the current thread. You can't start a transaction in a thread and commit it in another one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!!about the first question I Mean how can I know if the commit time is OK there is a place when I can find some KPI that say for istnace for one entity with 1000 rec the time should be 1 or 2 sec...?

Comment: about the third question I dont mean to do just the commit in the Trhead first to build the objects with the data and than call to the entitymanager to persist and commit all the data in thread ,is it good approch?

Comment: 1. You won't find these numbers, because it highly depends on your entities, their size, your hardware, your database, your network, etc. 2. That won't change much. Creating object in Java is very fast. Persisting them is what's slow.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely enable batch writing (and confirm that your database/driver supports it).

See,

http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-improve-jpa-performance-by-1825.html